# Laravel model: query from multiple array

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, relationship

I have a db table `Pharmacy` which has a column `area`, which is an `array`.

so for pharmacy `id=1` lets say `area = [10,12]`
for pharmacy `id=2` say `area = [1,2]`
for pharmacy `id=3` say `area = [1,10]`

I want to make an eloquent query which will search through all the data rows of `pharmacy table` and return only those pharmacy `id` which  has `area=10`

In return I should get `id = [1,3]`

How do I do this using eloquent query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses

```
$pharmacies  = Pharmacy::whereJsonContains('area', 10)
                ->pluck('id);
```